# Want to create a Event VF page?

Tags: visualforce, attachment, event

I would like to create a VF page similar to Event standard page. I am not able to add Recurrence, Reminder, Attachments to the my custom Event Vf page. Please help me how can i add these additional information to my custom page.

My code

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="CVFC_EventPage_ctrl" >
 <apex:form >  
  <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Calendar Details" columns="4">


         <column>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Event.Ownerid}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Event_view" action="{!rerender}">
                <apex:param name="ownerId_VF" value="{!Event.Ownerid}" assignTo="{!ownerId_VF}" />                    
            </apex:actionSupport>
         </apex:inputField>
         </column>
         <column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.WhatId}"/></column>
         <column>         
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.Subject}"/></column>
         <column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.WhoId}"/> </column>
         <column>           
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.IsAllDayEvent}"/></column>
         <column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.IsPrivate}"/></column>
         <column>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Event.StartDateTime}"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Event_view" action="{!rerender}">
                <apex:param name="startDate_VF" value="{!Event.StartDateTime}" assignTo="{!startDate_VF}"/>
            </apex:actionSupport>
         </apex:inputField></column>          
         <column></column>           
         <column>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.EndDateTime}"/></column>                                      
     </apex:pageBlockSection>  

     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Information" columns="4">
          <column>          
             <apex:inputField value="{!Event.Location}"/> </column>
          <column></column>    
     </apex:pageBlockSection>

     <apex:pageblockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveAndNew}"></apex:commandButton>
     </apex:pageblockButtons>         
  </apex:pageBlock>     

   </apex:form>


   <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection id="Event_view"  title="Event View" >


          <apex:datatable value="{!CevtWp}"  var="a" Width="700px" border="1">                
              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Time</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_Time}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Sun</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Sun}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Mon</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Mon}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Tue</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Tue}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Wed</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Wed}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Thu</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Thu}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Fri</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Fri}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column width="300px" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Sat</apex:facet> 
                  <apex:outputText value="{!a.By_subject_Sat}"/>
              </apex:column>                 
         </apex:datatable>   

          <apex:form >
          <apex:commandButton value="Click to View Events for Next Week" action="{!Click_next}"/></apex:form>

     </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: You should be able to add these fields and related lists to the page... Can you post your code so we can better help you troubleshoot?

Comment: i have edited my question with my code. I just want how to add Recurrence, Reminder, Attachments to my Vf page. This page is for Event. Also the field Phone, Email are showing error : Invalid field Phone for SObject Event

Comment: Where is your extension class.

Comment: If you have completely created the events visual force page and controller can you please copy paste the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code do I see you trying to add the Reminder and Recurrence fields. Please see the Salesforce documentation for the Event object for a full field listing here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm#topic-title

To add the attachements related list to the page you can use the apex:relatedList component.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock>
    You're looking at some related lists for {!account.name}:
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />

    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts">
        <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>

    <apex:relatedList list="Cases" title="Or you can keep the image, but change the text" />
</apex:page>
```

Documentation on that component can be found here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm